# Loading model with custom loss + keras

Tags: python, keras

In Keras, if you need to have a custom loss with additional parameters, we can use it like mentioned on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25029/custom-loss-function-with-additional-parameter-in-keras

```
def penalized_loss(noise):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true) - K.square(y_true - noise), axis=-1)
    return loss
```

The above method works when I am training the model. However, once the model is trained I am having difficulty in loading the model. When I try to use the custom_objects parameter in load_model like below

```
model = load_model(modelFile, custom_objects={'penalized_loss': penalized_loss} )
```

it complains `ValueError: Unknown loss function:loss`

Is there any way to pass in the loss function as one of the custom losses in `custom_objects` ? From what I can gather, the inner function is not in the namespace during load_model call. Is there any easier way to load the model or use a custom loss with additional parameters

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, there is! custom_objects expects the exact function that you used as loss function (the inner one in your case):

```
model = load_model(modelFile, custom_objects={ 'loss': penalized_loss(noise) })
```

Unfortunately keras won't store in the model the value of noise, so you need to feed it to the load_model function manually.

Comment: Do you mean that I will have to create a random variable noise when I am loading the trained model ? `noise` in my training keeps on changing hence affecting the loss value

Comment: I don't know what the variable noise is in your case, but you need to pass something to your penalized_loss function in order to return the loss function. If it's a random variable, you probably need to create a new one (or use an existing one) and passing that to your function, as you said.

Comment: If you are going to use the loaded model for testing, whichever noise variable you are going to pass it won't matter. You just want to be able to load your model :)

Comment: No problem! Please mark the answer as useful if you feel like it was :)

Comment: Because I ran this issue: it should be emphasized that the name of your inner function has to match the key in `custom_objects`. To avoid mistakes I do `loss=penalized_loss(noise); custom_objects={loss.__name__: loss}`

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to do this, but you are a life saver @rickyalbert

Comment: I appears like it doesn't recognize the nested function (I use focal loss, but it doesn't matter), I get "Unknown loss function" (for the nested model).

Answer (score 23):

If you are loading your model just for prediction (not training), you can set the compile flag to `False` in `load_model` as following:

```
model = load_model(model_path, compile=False)
```

This will not search for the loss function as it is only needed for compiling the model.

Comment: This did not work for me. With keras/tensorflow 2.5.0 I still got an error concerning the loss

Comment: Sorry getting back late. My tensorflow is 1.14 and the keras is 2.2.4. What format do you save your model? I am saving it in .h5 format as the following
checkpointer = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_path, verbose=1, monitor=, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode=)
where model_path is the path to your model with name extension of .h5.

Comment: You can also try custom_objects. something like
model = load_model(model_path, custom_objects={ 'weighted_binary_crossentropy': weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, weight=[1.,2.]) }) 
this is just an example that my loss name was weighted_binary_crossentropy and I had added weight. so I needed to give some weight when loading as well. I'm not sure how you have defined your loss, but you can just give some arbitrary variable when loading in the test time; I could give weight=[1.,1.]. Please search more for it and let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 5):

I  had the same problem and after many researches I can assume that this works:

1. At first, load your model and assign `compile=False`.
2. compile your model with your custom loss function.
3. retrain your model.

example:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   nn = np.square(y_true - y_pred)
   return nn

model = load_model("aaaa.h5", compile=False)
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=custom_loss)
model.fit(...)
```

Comment: This works for me in latest TF 2.12.0

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
import keras.losses
keras.losses.penalized_loss = penalized_loss
```

(after defining 'penalized_loss' function in your current 'py' file).

Comment: This doesn't work in latest Keras in TF 2.1 release.
Use `custom_objects` method instead that works fine. There's a bug in TensorFlow 2.1 Keras when loading class-based custom losses, but that looks to be fixed in [TF2.2.0rc2 pre-relsease version](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.2.0rc2/)

Answer (score 1):

@rickyalbert

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   nn = np.square(y_true - y_pred)
   return nn

model = load_model(modelFile, custom_objects={'loss': custom_loss})
```

You should pass the loss function as the object.