# Keras: How to load a model having two outputs and a custom loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have trained a Keras (with Tensorflow backend) model which has two outputs with a custom loss function. I need help in loading the model from disk using the `custom_objects` argument.

When compiling the model I have used the loss and loss_weights argument as follows:

```
losses = {
            'output_layer_1':custom_loss_fn,
            'output_layer_2':custom_loss_fn
         }

loss_weights = {
                'output_layer_1': 1.0, 
                'output_layer_2': 1.0
               }

model.compile(loss=losses, loss_weights=loss_weights, optimizer=opt)
```

The model is training without any problems. I save the model as follows:

```
model.save(model_path)
```

The reason I haven't defined "custom_loss_fn" here is because custom_loss_fn is defined inside another custom Keras layer.

My question is how do I load the model which is persisted to disk during inference. If it was a single ouput model I would load the model using custom_objects as described in this stackoverflow question: [Loading model with custom loss + keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373845/loading-model-with-custom-loss-keras)

```
model = keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'custom_loss_fn':custom_loss_fn})
```

But how to extend this in my case where I have two outputs with the losses and loss weights defined in a dictionary along with a custom loss function?

In other words, how should `custom_objects` be populated in this case where `losses` and `loss_weights` are defined as dictionaries?

I'm using Keras v2.1.6 with Tensorflow backend v1.8.0.

Comment: Have you tried  `custom_objects={
            'output_layer_1':custom_loss_fn,
            'output_layer_2':custom_loss_fn
         }`?

Comment: @Karl I just tried what you suggested. But with that I get this error. ```ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval```. Note that in another model with a single output and the same `custom_loss_fn` I don't get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can recompile the model on the loading side, the easiest way is to save just the weights: `model.save_weights()`. If you want to use save_model and have custom Keras layers, be sure they implement the `get_config` method (see [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1927) reference).
As for the ops without gradient, I have seen this while mixing tensorflow and Keras without using properly the `keras.backend` functions, but I can't help any more without the model code itself.

Comment: I'd accept this answer. I'm planning to go with recompiling the model and loading the saved weights. The link for `get_config` is also helpful. Thanks.