# ValueError: ('Invalid `distribution` argument: expected one of {"normal", "uniform"} but got', 'truncated_normal') , while importing the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras

```
# Keras
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
# from tensorflow.keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
# from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

# Flask utils
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

# Define a flask app
app = Flask(__name__)


# Model saved with Keras model.save()
MODEL_PATH = 'models/100_epoch.h5'

# Load your trained model
model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
```

This occurs when i try to load the model?/

Can you me fix this??
I am trying to deploy it in heroku

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading model with custom loss + keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373845/loading-model-with-custom-loss-keras)

Comment: Yes, tried that out. It worked. We have to put in the loss when we import the model. Thanks for the answer.